# r - using summarise_each() to count records ignoring NAs

Tags: r, dplyr

Is there a way to use `summarise_each()` to count the number of records in a data frame, but ignore `NA`s?

**Example / Sample Data**

```
df_sample <- structure(list(var_1 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA), var_2 = c(NA, 
  NA, NA, NA, 2, 1), var_3 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 3, 2), var_4 = c(NA_real_, 
  NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), var_5 = c(NA, 
  NA, NA, NA, 4, 3)), .Names = c("var_1", "var_2", "var_3", "var_4", 
  "var_5"), row.names = 5:10, class = "data.frame")

> df_samp
   var_1 var_2 var_3 var_4 var_5
5     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
6     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
7     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
8     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
9      1     2     3    NA     4
10    NA     1     2    NA     3
```

Using `summarise_each()` and `n()` counts all the records:

```
library(dplyr)
df_samp %>%
  summarise_each(funs(n()))

## result:
   var_1 var_2 var_3 var_4 var_5
1     6     6     6     6     6
```

I know that `n()` doesn't accept arguments, therefore is there another method I can use within `summarise_each()` that will ignore the `NA`s when counting the number of records, and will return zero if the variable is all `NA`?

**Desired Result**

```
   var_1 var_2 var_3 var_4 var_5
1     1     2     2     0     2
```

The following method gets me part of the way there, but I would also like to return a 0 for `var_4`:

```
df_samp %>%
  melt %>%
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>%
  group_by(variable) %>%
  summarise(records = n())

## result:
  variable records
1    var_1       1
2    var_2       2
3    var_3       2
4    var_5       2
```

Comment: A non-`dplyr` way could be `colSums(!is.na(df_sample))`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try:

```
df_sample %>% summarise_all(funs(sum(!is.na(.))))
```

Which gives:

```
#  var_1 var_2 var_3 var_4 var_5
#1     1     2     2     0     2
```

Comment: The number of `TRUE`. `!is.na(.)` will return `TRUE` for each non-`NA` value. Try `df_sample %>% mutate_each(funs(!is.na(.)))`

Comment: @ Steven Beaupré What's the answer if we we `summarise_at` instead of `summarise_each`?

Comment: `summarize_each` has deprecated, use `summarize_all` now

Answer (score 5):

Using `data.table`

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(df_sample)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) sum(!is.na(x)))]
 #   var_1 var_2 var_3 var_4 var_5
 #1:     1     2     2     0     2
```

Or with `base R`

```
 vapply(df_sample, function(x) sum(!is.na(x)), numeric(1))
 #var_1 var_2 var_3 var_4 var_5 
 #  1     2     2     0     2
```

Answer (score 0):

`sum(is.na(.)` is the right approach with the tidyverse.

Here's a `purrr` alternative:

```
df_sample %>% 
  map_df(function(x) sum(!is.na(x)))

df_sample %>% 
  map_df(~sum(!is.na(.x)))

df_sample %>% 
  map_dfr(~sum(!is.na(.x)))

df_sample %>% 
  map_dfc(~sum(!is.na(.x)))
```

...same same.